# Wordpress form not processing $_POST data

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

I made a template for my wordpress theme that has a form for the user to fill out. When the user access the page the from pulls information from the user meta data and fills out the fields he had previusly filled out. The user can then finish filling out the form, when he clicks submit, the form is supposed to update the user meta, but it doesn´t seem to be working, righ now when I click submit it records empty string into all the meta fields and forwards me to the url, maybe someone can shed some light, here is the code:

```
    <?php
/**
* Template Name: Cadastro Template
*/

if(isset($_POST['avancar'])){

    $user_id = $_POST['userID'];
    $primeiro_nome = $_POST['primeiro_nome'];
    $ultimo_nome = $_POST['ultimo_nome'];
    $cpf = $_POST['cpf'];
    $rg = $_POST['rg'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $sexo = $_POST['sexo'];
    $empresa = $_POST['empresa'];
    $endereco = $_POST['endereco'];
    $numero = $_POST['numero'];
    $complemento = $_POST['complemento'];
    $bairro = $_POST['bairro'];
    $cep = $_POST['cep'];
    $cidade = $_POST['cidade'];
    $estado = $_POST['estado'];
    $pais = $_POST['pais'];
    $telefone = $_POST['telefone'];
    $fax = $_POST['fax'];

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'primeiro_nome', $primeiro_nome);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'ultimo_nome', $ultimo_nome);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'cpf', $cpf);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'rg', $rg);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'dob', $dob);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'sexo', $sexo);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'empresa', $empresa);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'endereco', $endereco);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'numero', $numero);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'complemento', $complemento);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'bairro', $bairro);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'cep', $cep);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'cidade', $cidade);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'estado', $estado);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'pais', $pais);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'telefone', $telefone);
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'fax', $fax);


    ob_start(); // ensures anything dumped out will be caught

        // do stuff here
        $url = 'escolha-sua-camisa'; // this can be set based on whatever

            // clear out the output buffer
        while (ob_get_status()) 
        {
            ob_end_clean();
        }

        // no redirect
        header( "Location: $url" );

} 
?>
<html>

<body>
<div id="fundo">
<div class="abaCadastro">
    <div id="cadastro">
            <div id="controle">

            <?php 

            $user = wp_get_current_user();

            ?>



            <form id="cadastro" action="" method="post" class="">
                <div id="perfil">   
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Primeiro Nome</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="primeiro_nome" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'primeiro_nome', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                    </div>  
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Último Nome</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="ultimo_nome" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'ultimo_nome', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>CPF</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="cpf" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'cpf', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>RG</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="rg" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'rg', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>  
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Data de aniversário</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="dob" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'dob', true);?>" class="campo" placeholder="dd/mm/AAAA" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Sexo</p>
                        <p><select name="sexo" class="campo" size="1" form="cadastro">
                            <option value="M">Masculino</option>
                            <option value="F">Feminino</option>
                        </select>
                        </p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Empresa</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="empresa" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'empresa', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Endereço</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="endereco" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'endereco', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Número</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="numero" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'numero', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Complemento</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="complemento" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'complemento', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Bairro</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="bairro" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'bairro', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>CEP</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="cep" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'cep', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Cidade</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="cidade" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'cidade', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Estado</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="estado" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'estado', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>País</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="pais" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'pais', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Telefone</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="telefone" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'telefone', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Fax</p>
                        <p><input type="text" name="fax" value="<?php echo get_user_meta($user->ID, 'fax', true);?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" /></p>
                </div>
                <div id="campo">
                        <p>Foto</p>
                        <p><input type="file" name="file" id="file"></p>
                </div>

                <div id="clr" style="clear:both;"></div>

            </div>
            <input type="hidden" name="userID" value="<?php echo $user->ID;?>" class="campo" form="cadastro" />
            <input class="botao" type="submit" name="avancar" value="Próximo" id="submitbutton" />

            </form>

</div>

<?php wp_footer(); ?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Never eat user input raw! Do a `var_dump($_POST)` after submitting the form and show us the content

Comment: Just a side note, but you have multiple divs with the same ID (`campo`), and your form and a div have the same ID too (`cadastro`). Since you specify the `form` attribute on your input fields, the latter could even be a problem.